# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/proj/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am following "Spring in action - Craig Walls" book and encountered the below error message. Lot of the issues were mentioned in relation to `web.xml`. I am using Java config and not `web.xml`.

Controller in `spitter.web` package:

```
package spitter.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Dispatcher servlet configuration in `spittr.config` package:

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        //return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.Class};
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        //return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.Class};
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Rootconfig` in same package:

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spitter"}, excludeFilters={@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)})
public class RootConfig {

}
```

`WebConfig`:

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spitter.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
         configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

I am using Maven to resolving dependencies and Tomcat 9 within eclipse to run.

> Sep 17, 2016 4:46:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   INFO: Server startup in 5007 ms Sep 17, 2016 4:46:49 PM
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound WARNING:
>   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

My view `home.jsp` is in `WebContent/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp`.

Comment: Make sure that all the spring dependencies are added to the classpath...

Comment: Uncomment those commented lines in the `SpittrWebAppInitializer` and delete the line below them.

Comment: Also I'm sure about the `resolver.setPrefix("/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/");` and the fact that your view `home.jsp` is in `webContent/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp`.

Comment: what is the url you tried to access?

Comment: @Sekar, resolver.setPrefix("/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/"); and webContent/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp, there is some difference. webContent is not same as WebContent. Try to have a uniform name. It is case sensitive

Comment: @Ravindra: I have added _spring-context, spring-aop, spring-web, spring-webmvc, jstl-api, jstl, junit, spring-test_ dependencies in pom.xml and ran mvn install. Did i miss any other dependencies?

Comment: @Ali  Sorry about the type error. It is WebContent in my project as created by maven. I have commented the return to debug for the error. I have uncommented them now and issues still exists

Comment: @harshavmb: It was a typo error.      kuhajeyan: I am running through ecipse IDE an the url is _localhost:8080/proj/_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I made the below changes and it is working now.

I move the web.config to the same package as my constructor. Then created the war file and deployed in Apache Tomcat. Now i am able to access the website.